# Como crear API PHP con JWT

Tags: php

Quiero crear una API en php usando jwt, para lo mismo usare un paquete de composer.

El caso es que la voy a consumir con Angular,y entonces en mi archivo index.php tendria las rutas, es decir sin contenido html obviamente.

Previo a las rutas debo verificar si el usuario existe y si existe generar el token y devolverlo. Para lo mismo cree, ademas del archivo de conexion a la base de datos un archivo  "LoginController.php":

```
<?php
class LoginController{
    public $nombreusuario;
    public $contraseña;
    public function __construct(){
       

        }
       
    public function existeUsuario($nombreusuario,$contraseña){

    }
    public function crearToken(){
            if (existeUsuario($nombreusuario,$contraseña)){

            }
    }
}
?>
```

En mi index.php incluiria LoginController.php, para primero loguear el usuario.
La pregunta mia es: ¿como forzar a todos los controladores o a la API a que el token sea valido?
Es decir si no hay token o caduco que no pueda accederse a los metodos:¿Deberia codificar todas las rutas en index.php dentro de un if comprobando que el token sea valido?

Comment: Puedes crear un metodo que te valide el token, si la validacion del token falla, entonces envias un mensaje de error desde la API y que detenga la ejecucion del script